# Generate array of parameters and sub-parameters of JSDoc

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsdoc

I'm extending the `haruki` template to support sub parameters.

My JSDoc comment is:

```
/**
 * @constructor Foobar
 * param {Object} firstLevel
 * param {Object} [firstLevel.secondLevel]
 * param {Object} [firstLevel.secondLevel.thirdLevel]
 */
```

By default, `haruki` will export a flat array of parameters like this:

```
[
  { name: 'firstLevel' },
  { name: '[firstLevel.secondLevel]' },
  { name: '[firstLevel.secondLevel.thirdLevel]' }
]
```

But I need to get an output like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'firstLevel',
    parameters: [
      {
        name: 'secondLevel',
        parameters: [
          { name: 'thirdLevel' }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

My idea was to create an Object and then convert it to Array, doing so I can easily access to the nested parameters.

But I can't find a solution to the recursiveness problem...

My attempt is the one below:

```
function subParam(paramsObj, names, paramObj) {
    if (names.length === 1) {
        paramsObj[names[0]] = paramObj;
    } else {
        paramsObj[names[0]].parameters[names[1]] = paramObj;
    }
}

if (element.params) {
  var params = {};
  for (i = 0, len = element.params.length; i < len; i++) {
    var names = element.params[i].name.replace(/\[|\]/g, '').split('.');
    var obj = {
      'name': element.params[i].name,
      'type': element.params[i].type? element.params[i].type.names : [],
      'description': element.params[i].description || '',
      'default': hasOwnProp.call(element.params[i], 'defaultvalue') ? element.params[i].defaultvalue : '',
      'optional': typeof element.params[i].optional === 'boolean'? element.params[i].optional : '',
      'nullable': typeof element.params[i].nullable === 'boolean'? element.params[i].nullable : ''
    };
    subParam(params, names, obj);
  }
  // convert object to array somehow
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In *JavaScript*, key-value pairs where *key* is unique are best suited for *Object* and not *Array*.

Create your tree in an *Object*, then re-structure it to your desired *Array*

```
function transform(data) {
    var o = {}, i, str;

    function addPath(path) {
        var parts = path.split('.'),
            e = o, i = 0;
        for (; i < parts.length; ++i) {
            e = e[parts[i]] = e[parts[i]] || {};
        }
    }

    function transformPathObject(dir, obj) {
        var key, arr = [];
        for (key in obj) {
            arr.push(transformPathObject(key, obj[key]));
        }
        obj = {'name': dir};
        if (arr.length) obj.parameters = arr;
        return obj;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        str = data[i].name;
        str = str.replace(/^\[(.*)\]$|(.*)/, '$1$2');
        addPath(str);
    }
    return transformPathObject('__root__', o).parameters;
}
```

Usage

```
var data = [
    { name: 'firstLevel' },
    { name: '[firstLevel.secondLevel]' },
    { name: '[firstLevel.secondLevel.thirdLevel]' }
];

transform(data);
/*
[
    {
        "name": "firstLevel",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "secondLevel",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "thirdLevel"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
*/
```

---

Please note that you didn't show *Optional* data in your desired output

Comment: Thanks but as you noted, this will not include the optional data I'm trying to include in the "code attempt" I've posted. (note the `paramObj` argument)

Comment: @FezVrasta I was aiming at your `But I need to get an output like this:` example. Adding "optional" could be done by add a flag like `__optional__: true` to each new node created for an optional path (node didn't already exist). Adding a non-optional path would conversely delete `__optional__` from every existing node in it's path.